# how to count two values from three dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 datasets: company, post, postedited,

I want to count the numbers of companies' post and postedited. some companies post but did not edited. 
here is my query :

```
SELECT company.name, company.id, count(*), 
       ( select count(*) 
         from post, postedited 
         where post.id=postedited.post_id) 
from company, post as p 
where company.id=p.company_id 
group by company_id
```

the outcome of post is right, but the column of postedited is the same. what's wrong with my query?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Show the table schemas for all tables. Does `company_id` exist on `postedited` table?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is completely unrelated to the main query. It selects post and postedited and counts. You are showing this result for every row of the main query.

You want the subquery relate to the main query's post. So remove the post table from the subquery's from clause:

```
(select count(*) from postedited where postedited.post_id = p.id)
```

Now this subquery selects a count for the post_id of the main query's records. At last you must get the sum of the counts:

```
select 
  c.name, c.id, count(*) as posts, 
  sum(select count(*) from postedited pe where pe.post_id = p.id) as edits
from company c
join post p on p.company_id = c.id
group by c.id;
```

You can achieve the same thus:

```
select 
  c.name, c.id, count(distinct p.id) as posts, count(pe.post_id) as edits
from company c
join post p on p.company_id = c.id
left join postedited pe on pe.post_id = p.id
group by c.id;
```

Comment: `count(pe.post_id)` in my second query counts edits. Shawn's `count(distinct pe.post_id)` counts edited posts. Decide which of the two you want. Shawn's query moreover also selects companies without posts, which is another thing you may want or not.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I am new to sql, need more practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name AS companyName
    , c.id AS companyID
    , COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS postCount
    , COUNT(DISTINCT pe.post_id) AS postEditCount
FROM company c
LEFT OUTER JOIN post p ON p.Company_ID = c.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN postEdited pe ON pe.Company_ID = c.ID
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

That will give you a list of all companies in your company table with a count of each of their posts and edited posts. If you need to further query against that dataset, you can. Or you can add a WHERE clause to the above query to filter it.

And I agree, please don't use comma syntax. It's very easy to produce unintended results, and it doesn't give a good representation of what you're actually querying against. Plus, it's no longer standard and being deprecated in many flavors of SQL. Good JOIN syntax will make your life much easier.

Comment: really appreciate for your help!